# Can't define ++ operator in C++, what's the issue here?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, switch-statement, operator-overloading

I'm working through Bjarne Stroustrup's The C++ Programming Language and I'm stuck on one of the examples. Here's the code, and aside from whitespace differences and comments my code is identical to what's in the book (p.51).

```
enum class Traffic_light { green, yellow, red};
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Traffic_light light = Traffic_light::red;
//    DEFINING OPERATORS FOR ENUM CLASSES
//    enum classes don't have all the operators, must define them manually.
    Traffic_light& operator++(Traffic_light& t) {
        switch (t) {
            case Traffic_light::green:
                return t = Traffic_light::yellow;
            case Traffic_light::yellow:
                return t = Traffic_light::red;
            case Traffic_light::red:
                return t = Traffic_light::green;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Yet when I compile it with `clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Weverything main.cpp` on Mac OS X 10.9 I get the following errors:

```
main.cpp:24:9: error: expected expression
        switch (t) {
        ^
main.cpp:32:6: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    }
     ^
     ;
```

The real baffeler is the `expected expression` error, but the `expected ;` is problematic as well. What have I done?

Comment: You are trying to define a function inside a function. You can't.

Comment: Just do it outside your main function...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Traffic_light& operator++(Traffic_light& t) is a function with name operator ++. Each function shall be defined outside any other function. So place the definition of the operator before main.

Comment: That's the issue. Thanks. I'm used to languages like JavaScript where you can put functions where ever the heck you want. I'll accept the answer as soon as StackOverflow lets me. (stupid time delay)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have your code running:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74c0cbc5a8c48e47

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum class Traffic_light { 
    green, 
    yellow, 
    red
};

Traffic_light & operator++(Traffic_light & t) {
    switch (t) {
        case Traffic_light::green:
            t = Traffic_light::yellow;
        break;
        case Traffic_light::yellow:
            t = Traffic_light::red;
        break;
        case Traffic_light::red:
            t = Traffic_light::green;
        break;
    }
    return t;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Traffic_light & t)
{
    switch(t)
    {
        case Traffic_light::green:
            os << "green";
        break;
        case Traffic_light::yellow:
            os << "yellow";
        break;
        case Traffic_light::red:
            os << "red";
        break;
    }
    return os;

}

int main()
{
    Traffic_light light = Traffic_light::red;

    std::cout << "Ligth:" << ++light << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Ligth:" << ++light << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Ligth:" << ++light << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems:

First, you are attempting to implement a function (`operator++`) inside another function (`main`).  C++ does not allow this (with the exception of lambdas).

Second, you are only implementing a prefix increment, so `++light` will work, but `light++` will not.  You should implement them both.  An example of it can be found [here](http://ideone.com/veb85I).

Comment: C/C++ alow to declare one function within another function. They do not allow to define a function.